# How to change the output of lemmatized words that are presented as list comprehension?

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet, lemmatization, part-of-speech

I am struggling with my lemmatization approach because the output provides the following:

| Row | Lemmatized |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [i, , b, e, , o, k, a, y, , ... |

While I wanted the output to look like the following so that I can extract into a CSV file and do further analysis:

| Row | Lemmatized |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | i be okay |

I am using a CSV file to do my analysis and applied the following approach:

1. Apply parts of speech tags
2. Convert parts of speech tags to wordnet's format using NLTK's word lemmatizer
3. Apply the NLTK’s word lemmatizer within the list comprehension.

My code is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:xxxxx")
rws=df.loc[:, ['MESSAGE']]
rws['pos_tags'] = rws['MESSAGE'].apply(nltk.tag.pos_tag)
def get_wordnet_pos(tag):
    if tag.startswith('J'):
        return wordnet.ADJ
    elif tag.startswith('V'):
        return wordnet.VERB
    elif tag.startswith('N'):
        return wordnet.NOUN
    elif tag.startswith('R'):
        return wordnet.ADV
    else:
        return wordnet.NOUN
rws['wordnet_pos'] = rws['pos_tags'].apply(lambda x: [(word, get_wordnet_pos(pos_tag)) for (word, pos_tag) in x])
wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
rws['lemmatized'] = rws['wordnet_pos'].apply(lambda x: [wnl.lemmatize(word,tag) for word,tag in x])
```

Can anyone guide me about what am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Got it sorted guys , it was something very simple (EMBARASSED). My apologies for not wording it right. I wanted to put each row back into strings. Therefore, the code I have used was :

```
rws["final"]= rws["lemmatized"].str.join(" ")
```